# Container, Row, Cols in kendo-react-ui

Tags: reactjs, layout, kendo-react-ui

I am using components from kendo-react-ui for my react project. I am trying to use Layout properties like Container, Row, Cols to make it responsive as we have in bootstrap 4. Please find my code below :

```
<div className="container cont">
    <div className="row">
        <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <Button primary={true}>Add User</Button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above code takes up entire row. I am using kendo-theme-material. Could anyone let me know how to achieve this in kendo-react-ui ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you added bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Xizario
After contacting kendo's support team, I came to know that we have to install bootstrap dependency separately to make the application responsive. I have added reactstrap which uses bootstrap 4.

Thanks